# How to pass PHP parameter to Python and open whatsapp

Tags: python, php, whatsapp

I'm trying to develop an a simple web app with PHP and Python.
The objective is that when passing the whatsapp number through PHP the python code is executed.
I am using the **pywhatkit** package and from the console I can execute it correctly but when I do it from PHP nothing happens.
Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

**My PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
    $para1 = "+whatsappnumber";
    $cmd = "python test.py $para1";
    $result = exec($cmd, $output, $return);
    printf("Command exited with code %d, full output follows: %s", $return, print_r($output,1));
 ?>
```

**My Python code:**

```
import sys
import pywhatkit as kit

who = sys.argv[1]
kit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(who, "I send from PHP and Python, ohmygosh!")
```

I'm starting to program with Python and I still don't understand it very well. From already thank you very much. Sorry for my English! ;-)

Comment: first you should check in web server logs if there is no error message. Or you could evn write some values in log directly from PHP and Python to see if you get correct values. You could also try with `/full/path/to/python /full/path/to/script.py`

Comment: Hi @furas! I check log error and and no errors. The fullpath I also tried and without positive results. In cmd I put python test.py +whatsappnumber and works perfectly. The problem its in PHP.

Comment: in PHP you should save some logs in own log. You should also check if server allow to use `exec()` because some servers block it for security reason. You could also check if you can run `exec` with other programs or with something simpler - like `python -V` to get Python version.

Comment: @furas I already tried making a program that would generate a txt from PHP passing variables to PYHTON and it worked fine. That's why i'm so confused

Comment: maybe start with simpler script which only safe message in file to check if it really work. Other problem can be that web server may runs as different user (apache usually uses `www-data`), with different privileges and settings.